# Comparing items in onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list and when a item is premium and not purchased yet, i'll apply a filter in the ImageView.

The problem is, everything works when i start the app, but when i start scroll, the other itens starts to get the gray filter as well. And then the filter is on everyline line.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ThemeViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Tema t = temaList.get(position);
        boolean comprado = bp.isPurchased(t.getSkuTema());
        holder.temaTexto.setText(t.getNomeTema());
        holder.temaIcone.setImageResource(t.getIconeTema());
        if(t.getIsPremium() != 0){
            Log.d("Adapter", "Posição: "+ position + " is Premium: " + t.getIsPremium());
            ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
            matrix.setSaturation(0);
            ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
            holder.temaIcone.setColorFilter(filter);
        }
    }
```

Only position < 6 result in "isPremium = 0", and I have 10 items.

My log

```
01-24 14:22:45.048 17282-17282/llamaze.com.br.whattodraw D/Adapter: Posição: 7 is Premium: 1
01-24 14:22:45.071 17282-17282/llamaze.com.br.whattodraw D/Adapter: Posição: 8 is Premium: 1
01-24 14:22:45.117 17282-17282/llamaze.com.br.whattodraw D/Adapter: Posição: 9 is Premium: 1
```

Am I doing someting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `RecyclerView` is called like this because it *recycles* its views.

That said, when scrolling you *premium* views will get reused for *non-premium* rows as well.

All you need to do is implement the `else` branch to your `if` statement where you remove the filter, if it is *non-premium*.

Comment: What can I call on "else" just to dont do nothing? Any idea?

Comment: No, you need to set the color filter back to the default within your else block.

Comment: @Spotik `holder.temaIcone.setColorFilter(null)`

Comment: I use "clearColorFilter()" in 'else' and works... thks dude!